# is it possible to ring an alert sound if certain conditional formatting is true in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 cells A1,B1 containing numerical values 10,5.
When i subtract B1 from A1(10-5) the answer comes in cell C1 which is 5.
I have set the conditional formatting in a way that if the answer in C1 is less than 5 it should change the cell color to red,  which is working.
I want Google sheet to ring an alert sound at the same time too, if value in C1 is less than 5.

How do i accomplish this?

I tried a VBA in excel which worked there but google sheet doesn't support VBA so i really dont know how to do this in google sheet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.